# Firefox rendering svgs incorrrectly

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I have firefox 43 and none of my svg styles are rendering properly. If I inspect it, the styles are computed, but they don't show up at all. Clip-path and border-radius both do not work. Any ideas? I'm building the clippath and the images/circles all within the same svg, in the same file, but applying the clippath in css.

HTML

```
  <svg class="svg-graphic" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clippath">
      <circle class="clip" cx="200" cy="500" r="50"/>
      <circle class="clip" cx="600" cy="700" r="70"/>
      <circle class="clip" cx="800" cy="400" r="40"/>
      <circle class="clip" cx="1400" cy="600" r="60"/>
      <circle class="clip" cx="1700" cy="300" r="80"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <image class="svg-image" xlink:href="http://www.placecage.com/gif/300/300" width="300" height="300" x="50" y="350"/>
    <text class="expand-text" x="200" y="450"
        font-family="Helvetica"
        font-size="25"
        fill="#ffffff">
    <tspan text-anchor="middle" x="200" dy="1.4em">
      Bacon ipsum
    </tspan><tspan text-anchor="middle" x="200" dy="1.4em">
      dolor amet
    </tspan><tspan text-anchor="middle" x="200" dy="1.4em">
      doner prosciutto
    </tspan><tspan text-anchor="middle" x="200" dy="1.4em">
      jerky
      </tspan>
    </text>
    <circle class="circle"  fill="#CC66FF" cx="200" cy="500" r="150"/>
    <text class="svg-text" fill="#ffffff" x="168" y="510"
        font-family="Helvetica"
        font-size="25">
      Hello
    </text>
  </svg>
```

CSS

```
.circle{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
z-index: 4;
clip-path: url("#clippath");
}

.svg-image {
z-index: 4;
border-radius: 50%;
clip-path: url(#clippath);
}

svg{
display: block;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Here's what I see on firefox
[image: Here's what I see on firefox]

And here's what I see in Chrome/Safari
[image: And here's what I see in Chrome/Safari]

Comment: Firefox is correct, Chrome is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand, in the other question they are referencing a seperate svg and trying to apply it to another svg. I'm not doing that. I can't even get simple css styles like border radius to apply to an svg image.

Comment: You just can't set `border` on any element inside an svg element (except HTML ones in `<foreignObject>` ). Here is a list of what you can change through CSS : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties. Also, for the `clip-path` attribute, it works just fine in your example if you do declare the css in the same doc as your svg markup. The only thing is that you are drawing a filled circle over the clipped image...

Comment: You can't write url(#id) in a CSS file because that means url(thecssfile.css#id) and there's no element with that id **in the CSS file**. All your elements are in the HTML file.

Comment: @RobertLongson but if the css is defined in a `<style>` element inside the HTML document, this will work just fine. OP isn't clear if the CSS is an external file or not.

Comment: The effect is consistent with separate files. i.e is incorrectly applied on Chrome but correctly fails on Firefox

Comment: My css is declared in a seperate css file. So basically I just need to move to css into my html file?

Comment: @Kaiido, I'm drawing that circle over the image, and then ,when you hover over the image, tweening the opacity of the circle overlay to 0 so the image appears. Here's my codepen I'm working off of that shows my code and the behavior. http://codepen.io/kathryncrawford/pen/JYBRVR

Comment: Hey hey! Moving the styles into my HTML file worked like a charm. Thanks guys! If one of you posts an answer, I'll mark it for you!